# How, depending on the settings in the property file, force service to use a particular repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I set `VM options` to `-Dmyapp.conf=config/my.properties`. I need to use this file content to select which repository to use. I use SpringBoot.

There is service, now it gives `Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'MyRepository' type`:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repository;
...}
```

Repositories:

```
public interface MyRepository  {...}

@Repository
public class MyRepositoryImpl01 implements MyRepository  {...}

@Repository
public class MyRepositoryImpl02 implements MyRepository  {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) for that purpose.

```
@Profile("profile1")
@Repository
public class MyRepositoryImpl01 implements MyRepository  {...}

@Profile("profile2")
@Repository
public class MyRepositoryImpl02 implements MyRepository  {...}
```

Then in the property file you need: `spring.profiles.active=profile1` or `spring.profiles.active=profile2`.

Comment: Thank you, it seems what I'm looking for! One more thing: how ot activate profile not from `-Dspring.profiles.active="myProfile"` but from file? `-Dmyapp.conf=config/my.properties`

Comment: add property `spring.profiles.active` to your property file

Comment: Ah, problem was in renamed application.properties :'((( Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would actually consider having this logic in some Java Config (a class annotated with @Configurtation) than in both (or possibly N) repositories.

You could use [@ConditionalOnProperty](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) and in this Java Config you would encapsulate entire logic of this "repository selection". This would be a benefit since you would only have 1 bean of the specified type, which in turn could be useful if your repositories connect to databases that are not available for certain configuration options.